# How can you get the height of an swf to expand with the content?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, height

I am creating a site in flash that is reading in entries from a database. I want the swf to expand downward on the html page so the user can use the browser scroll bars to see all the content. I don't want to paginate everything into a 800 px high swf or something - I want the page to expand just like it would if it were html. Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do exactly that in a private project.  We have a function that uses ExternalInterface.call (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html):

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call('resizeScene', newHeight)
```

to call a javascript function which simply resizes the div element:

```
function resizeScene(newHeight)
{
    document.getElementById('website').style.height = parseFloat(newHeight) + 'px';
}
```

You may also want to investigate

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html#align

and

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode

Comment: Works great, thanks! I knew about ExternalInterface but didn't know the flash would expand automatically.